How to avoid the "Allow Macros" confirmation in QlikView 11 with NPrinting?
In my work environment, I use QlikView 11 along with NPrinting, which automatically sends reports to other users. However, I encounter an issue where certain reports use macros, and NPrinting stops until I manually confirm "Allow Macros."
I’ve tried looking into the Settings.ini file for a solution, but I haven’t had any success.
Is there a way to automatically allow macros in QlikView 11 so that NPrinting can run without interruptions? Are there any settings or alternative solutions that might resolve this issue?

I havent used NPrinting and QV app with macro but have a look at the Qlik Support answer that might be related to the same problem/issue
NPrinting hangs on QlikView application containing Macros 
Posting the article content here as well (in case that the link stops working in the future):

Description
NPrinting is not able to run the macro from the QlikView application. This is because Allow Safe Macros in QlikView is not set for NPrinting user ID.
Resolution

Open the QlikView installation folder (normally it is C:\Program Files\QlikView)
Click on Shift and right click on the Qv.exe file
Choose "Run as a different user" in the window that opens
Enter the NPrinting user ID and password.
Open the QlikView document.

You should see a message asking to allow macros. Choose "Allow Safe Macros".
You should then be able to run the macro from the QlikView application

